# Which jar files do I have to put in the lib folder for these import statements to work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts2, jar

I am following a Struts2 tutorial. It tells me to import the listed classes. But it does not tell me which jar files to put in the lib folder under `WEB-INF` folder.

These are the import statements that I have in my action class:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionError;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionError;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
```

I have the following jars in the lib folder. But apparently these are not enough.

```
Commons-IO 2.2
Commons-lang3-3.0
Commons-logging-1.1.3
Commons-fileupload-1.2
Freemarker-2.3.19
Javaassist- 3.12.1 GA
Ognl-3.0.6
Sqljdbc4
Org.apache.commons.io-2.4
Struts2-core 2.3.16
Xwork-core 2.3.16
```

Can someone tell me which jars I should put in the lib folder?

Comment: Which classes are throwing the class not found?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21044848/1654265

Comment: import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionError;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

Comment: If a Struts 2 tutorial is telling you to import Struts 1 classes, that tutorial is fundamentally broken.

Comment: @user3123222 *Not enough*, see my answer to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the import statement you are using servlet API. So, you need to add Java EE dependencies. But it should be available on classpath only at compile time. It means that you should add this jars to the build path but not to the `WEB-INF/lib`. Servlet API jars contain in every web server which is running a servlet container. These classes already loaded by the web server before your application is deployed. And it doesn't allowed to load them twice. That's why you shouldn't put them to `WEB-INF/lib`. What should you use from Java EE package

```
javax.servlet.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044813/573032) answer if you are not using Maven to get a clue about libraries used with Struts2 project.

If you are using Maven, then use this jars with the scope `provided`. More details are [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope).

Finally, you are using Struts 1 classes in import, so if you want to use these classes with Struts2 project then you need additionally

```
struts2-struts1-plugin-2.3.16.jar
struts-core-1.3.10.jar
```