# org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter in Struts 2 using embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, struts2, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat

I have a Struts 2.5.5 web app. I want to run it with integrated Tomcat. I am using the below plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9090</port>
          <path>/IADD/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

**My `pom.xml` looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.citi.168902</groupId>
    <artifactId>ismart-project-app-web</artifactId>
    <version>V1.${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ismart-project-app-web</name>
    <url></url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <asm.version>3.3</asm.version>
        <axis.version>1.4.1</axis.version>
        <bsh.version>2.0b4</bsh.version>
        <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.4</commons-beanutils.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2.2</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-csv.version>1.6</commons-csv.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.11</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-net.version>3.6</commons-net.version>
        <dom4j.version>2.1.3</dom4j.version>
        <dwr.version>3.0.2-RELEASE</dwr.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.10.6</ehcache.version>
        <gson.version>1.4</gson.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.19</jfreechart.version>
        <jfreecommon.version>1.0.23</jfreecommon.version>
        <jsch.version>0.1.55</jsch.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <jsqlparser.version>1.4</jsqlparser.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <log4j.version>2.13.2</log4j.version>
        <opencsv.version>2.3</opencsv.version>
        <openjpa.version>2.3.0</openjpa.version>
        <poi.version>4.1.1</poi.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.2</quartz.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.25</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <struts2.version>2.5.26</struts2.version>
        <springframwork.version>4.3.26.RELEASE</springframwork.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.27</snakeyaml.version>     
        <xlsx-streamer.version>2.1.0</xlsx-streamer.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.admin.client</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.9</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->    
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.security</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframwork.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframwork.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>${dwr.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-net.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>${jsch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId> <artifactId>axis</artifactId> 
            <version>${axis.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreecommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
            <version>${jsqlparser.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId> <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId> 
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
            <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
            <version>${xlsx-streamer.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId> <artifactId>bsh</artifactId> 
            <version>${bsh.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>IADD</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
             <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9090</port>
          <path>/IADD/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/generated</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>./src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>MANIFEST.MF</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>./src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>MANIFEST.MF</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                  
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**My `web.xml`:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>IADD</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>validate</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
        

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>DWR Servlet</description>
        <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowGetForSafariButMakeForgeryEasier</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>/com/citi/clg/originations/strategic/schedule/scheduler.properties</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
         <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
     </listener>
     
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.citi.clg.originations.strategic.schedule.IaddScheduler</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>iSmartLogin</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.citi.clg.originations.strategic.thread.DahcHealthCheckListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
</web-app>
```

I am doing a mvn cleam install followed by `mvn tomcat7:run`

**But I am getting the below error:**

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 24, 2021 2:43:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jun 24, 2021 2:43:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/IADD/] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 24, 2021 2:43:00 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `pom.xml` dependencies, you should notice that two different versions of [Servlet API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) was used at compile and it is not the same at runtime on the server even if you set the scope `provided` wrong library is loaded on classpath. It simtimes happens if you have mismatch source and targeted version of classes loaded by different classloaders.

Check your classpath on the server to see what libraries are loaded and which classloaders when you start your application.

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21312786/573032) answer give you some clue.